# Decrease openssl SECLEVEL in conf for only one connection

Tags: 22.04, openssl

I'm working on establishing a connection to a database server without encryption, as TLS isn't supported by the database system. Currently, I'm using isql to validate the connection:

```
isql -v -k "Driver={Driver SQL Server};Server=mysql-server;Database=DATABASE;UID=user;PWD=pwd;"
```

However, I encountered an issue with error code `0x2746`, indicating the absence of TLS support. After researching online, it seems that reducing the `SECLEVEL` to 0 in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` resolves the problem:

```
[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
```

After rebooting, the connection works fine. But setting the `SECLEVEL` to 0 system-wide isn't ideal for obvious reasons. Instead, I'd prefer a per-connection configuration. So, I attempted the following:

```
[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2

[mysql-server]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
```

However, this produces the same error as mentioned at the beginning of this post.
Any insights or suggestions on achieving per-connection configuration without compromising system security would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if (rather than a section within the default file) you can use a whole separate config file, passed to `isql` via the `OPENSSL_CONF` [environment variable](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/config.5ssl.html#environment) ?